# Surprising high bandwidth on my ISP's network

Tags: networking, internet, bandwidth

I live in India. The plan which I have taken from my ISP gives me 130 Kbps on internet and 1 MBps on peering network.

I download certain (NOT popular) videos from Vimeo, and I found out today that a certain server (skyfiregcs-a.akamaihd.net) located in the CA, US is giving me speeds of 1 MBps while downloading from Vimeo (some Vimeo videos of my interest happen to be hosted on that server).

My question: How can a peering network be so big that it stretches from India to US, since I am not downloading any popular videos?

Or is it a network administration snag?

Comment: You do understand that Akamai,  is a really large CDN network, likely one of the largest in the world.  In other words, Akamai while based in the US, likely has hardware in India.

Comment: @Ramhound: I don't know. Thanks for the info. I will look up Akamai, I have seen this server used for Facebook and Instagram content as well. I will look up what is CDN as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Peering" is not a network.

A peering is when two network operators connect together directly. The size of each others' networks are not directly relevant. You could more accurately describe the two networks as "peer**ed** networks". The opposite of a peered network is a transit(ed) network, where your ISP has to pay a third-party transit provider to carry your data to its destination network.

For both ISPs and CDNs like Akamai, costs are minimized by peering with as many providers as possible. That's what they do. Because it's cheaper for the ISP, they can provide higher speeds to it.

Major (e.g. national) ISPs often have networks that reach major peering locations and key datacentres in neighbouring countries so this is not at all unusual. CDNs, similarly, have large global networks. Many of these rent shared fibre from the T1 telcos so don't completely "own" all the cabling, allowing their networks to span much larger areas than if they had to wire up the globe themselves.